# Correction factor for monitor based off orthogonal regression

Tags: calibration, monitor

I'm seeking some clarity about providing a correction factor for an instrument based off orthogonal regression. Currently I have a machine I built myself, co-located with a reference monitor recording PM10 pollutant data. I want to eventually be able to deploy this station on its own and trust its recording reasonable data, so am looking for a way to calibrate my station against the reference machine. After reading around the topic, it seems orthogonal regression is the usual form of analysis, rather then basic linear, as it assumed random error for both the reference and the built_station.

I have used the below example of data for the purpose of this question, when in reality I have over 9 months of data at 15 minute intervals. Where x= reference_station and y=built_station

[image: Example of data measured at 15 minute intervals]

What my end goal is to perform orthogonal regression on a data set like the above example and perform a correction factor, so I can re-deploy my machine and say it is, to some degree of confidence, recording suitable data. I'm unsure if the equation is similar for linear regression and am stumped at where to begin.

I'm familiar enough with linear regression and the correction factor I can form based off that, where x=(y-c)/m, but I'm struggling to piece together the information required to do a similar level of analysis based off orthogonal regression.

If anyone could help with some clarity around the topic and how I could achieve a final result, whereby if I apply the obtained correction factor based off the analysis of the two stations side by side, I can use this correction factor for my station and potentially achieve more accurate measurements of PM in my area.

Comment: Has this got anything to do with an EE question or is it just about a non_EE formula?

Comment: First plot each (mine, reference) point pair and see what the cloud looks like over several 12 hour periods (and possibly week by week too). These pairs look fairly uncorrelated to me. But if the clouds all have a similar form you may be able to find an approximate regression. If not, find out why. Are there environmental factors (like rain, temperature or mist) that you need to correct for?

Comment: @BrianDrummond RH is usually something that cause an issue, but a heater has been deployed to try and minimize the effect of it. The hope would be that these things would be corrected for and outliers caused by mist would be removed.

Using basic linear regression for a larger dataset it gave approximately a 0.7 R2. Not great, but not the worst either. There just seems to be some missing links in my understanding regarding the jump from linear to orthogonal regression and how i can use the equation to get a correction factor.

Comment: my apologies @Andy aka, i found a similar thread on this channel which had some really good responses but didn't quite satisfy what i was looking for. I guess it falls under the category of calibration of EE equipment